# Modifying a reference type passed as parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance, reference-type

I have been [reading up](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html#ref) on passing reference types in C# and I am unsure about a specific situation.

Example Code:

```
public class Foo
{
  int x;
  public SetX(int value)
  {
    x = value;
  }
  public int Zed
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
public class Bar : Foo
{
  //suffice it to say, this is SOME inherited class with SOME unique elements
}

...
void Func (Foo item)
{
  Bar child = item as Bar;
  child.Zed = 2;
  child.SetX(2); //situation in question.
}
...
Bar y = new Bar();
y.Zed = 1;
y.SetX(3);
Func(y);
```

I know that `Zed` is not changed in `y` but is `x` modified? Or is `x` in still `3` after passing `y` to `Func` and treating it as a `Bar`?

Comment: When you pass `y` (which is a `Foo`) to `Func`, then `item as Bar` will return `null`, resulting in a NullReferenceException when you assign `child.Zed = 2`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu how would it be `null` if Bar is inherited from `type Foo`? `Foo` exists and has memory created for it, I am just treating that memory as `Bar`.

Comment: @bwtrent that's not how types work in C#. It would be `null`.

Comment: @bwtrent: You cannot treat an object as a `Bar` unless the object is an instance of `Bar` or a class derived from `Bar`. `Foo` is neither.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. I have edited my example code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one, mutable `Bar` instance through the whole process.

```
Foo y = new Bar();
y.Zed = 1;
y.SetX(3);
Func(y);
```

`y.Zed == 2` and `y.x == 2` at the end of this, because those are the values they were assigned in `Func`. The fact that one was set via a property and the other via a method is unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

> > I know that Zed is not changed in y but is x modified? Or is x in still 3 after passing y to Func and treating it as a Bar?

X will be modified. It will be `2` due to following line in `Func`

```
child.SetX(2); //situation in question.
```